# Invoke a main class method from other class in Android

Tags: java, android

So I don't know if this is possible, so in more detail:

I have my main class `public class MainAR extends Activity{` and an object `GUIManager` of other class. From that other I want to call a method from `MainAR`:

```
public class MainAR extends Activity{
    ...
    private GUIManager mGUIManager;
    ...
    mGUIManager = new GUIManager(getApplicationContext());
    ...
    public void mehtodMain(){
        ...
    }
}
```

And then the other class:

```
public class GUIManager {
    private MainAR mainClass;

    public GUIManager(Context context){
        //mainClass = ???
        ...
    }

    private method(){
        mainClass.mehtodMain();
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to initialize `mainClass`...

Comment: you should have done a lil research..because this is a cheesy question.. just instantiate it in your constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide it an instance of your main class

```
mGUIManager = new GUIManager(MainAR.this);

public GUIManager(MainAR mainClass){
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }
```

Comment: I still get confused with this issue, I think is a big "blank" in my programing skills. So "an instance" is kind of a linked reference?

Comment: This is cross referencing and a ugly practice.Child objects should be avoided to also reference the parent. A better way is the observer pattern. Via interfaces where child holds an interface which parent implements so the if method can be called from child via interface.But java is poor in this in general.