# Invoke a method from a simple class from a BroadcastReceiver on the main Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

Following a little with this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25574303/3380233) I know it might be too basic, but I have searched trough the web and I find this a little complicated (Maybe more by concept...). I just don´t know which method would be the best...

My short code is:

```
public class MainAR extends Activity{
    ...
    private GUIManager mGUIManager;
    ...
    mGUIManager = new GUIManager(getApplicationContext(), MainAR.this);
    ...

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                mGUIManager.method(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the other class:

```
public class GUIManager {
    private MainAR mainClass;

    public GUIManager(Context context, MainAR classy){
        mainClass = classy;
        ...
    }

    public void method(boolean op){
        // set something to op...
    }
}
```

So I just can´t make it run, it compiles but gets me an error... the line giving trouble is `mGUIManager.method(true);`. I have tryed to use handlers, but no success, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I´m adding the error that Eclipse is reporting me, it doesn´t sound (to me) related, but every time I take away that line `mGUIManager.method(true);` the program doesn´t crash.

```
W/dalvikvm(22042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f409a8)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22042): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.ARPhone.phone_ar_demo.MainAR$1@414bada0
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:798)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at com.ARPhone.phone_ar_demo.MainAR.getStrFromName(MainAR.java:484)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at com.ARPhone.phone_ar_demo.MainAR.access$0(MainAR.java:483)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at com.ARPhone.phone_ar_demo.MainAR$1.onReceive(MainAR.java:425)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:788)
E/AndroidRuntime(22042):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What's the error? Stack trace?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, added @AnubianNoob, thanks!

Comment: Think you've forgotten to show us a a method: `MainAR.getStrFromName`, since this is where the issue stems from. It's a `NullPointerException`, which ends in a `RuntimeException`. Also looking at your other question (the one you linked to), maybe you should from the beginning, by learning basic concepts about Java as well and then afterwards moving on to Android. Sorry for being so blunt, but you have to learn how to crawl before you can walk :-)

Comment: Ok, I have a project to achieve... thats why I'm trying this, but definetly you're right about the step by step advice. So the problem is basically in other method! (MainAR.getStrFromName). I´ll do debuging and with this clues I will try to fix this issue. Thanks!